# Erro de compilação com struct

Tags: c, struct, include

Ao tentar compilar estou enfrentando o seguinte erro:

```
..: error: storage size of 'PPFila' isn't known
..: error: storage size of 'AUTFila' isn't known
```

Nesta linha de código

```
struct  Fila PPFila, AUTFila;
```

A `struct` Fila esta sendo esta em um outro arquivo `queue.c` e estou acessando utilizando  `#include "Queue.h"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a `struct Fila` no arquivo `Queue.h` e não no `queue.c`. E, obviamente, include o arquivo `Queue.h` onde vc deseja que ela seja usada

Comment: Exatamente, devo criar as `strucs` e declarações de métodos no .h deixando somente as implementações no .c, não tinha notado isso, obrigado

Comment: @LucasFernandes: Isso não é verdade! A definição (implementação) de `structs` no `.h` faz com que seus membros sejam acessíveis pelos clientes da interface (membros públicos), definições feitas no `.c` (separadas da declaração) fazem com que os membros da sua `struct` sejam inacessíveis pelos clientes da interface (membros privados). O segundo tipo se chama "Estrutura Opaca".

Comment: @LucasFernandes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type

Comment: @Lacobus não confunda  definição (implementação) com declaração. O que vc disse não é correto. Definição vai no .c e declaração no .h Uma declaração é quando vc apresenta o nome ao programa e a definição é quando vc a instancia. Ao fazer `struct File PPFila;` é uma definição e normalmente vai em um .c

Comment: @Amadeus: Acho que você precisa revisar seus conceitos: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration

Comment: @Lacobus Não entendi o que vc quis dizer com o seu último comentário. O que está no link que vc forneceu é exatamente o que eu tinha comentado anteriormente. Então, qual conceito eu deveria revisar?

Comment: @Amadeus: Isso é uma declaração: `struct foobar;` e isso é uma definição: `struct foobar { int x; };`. Não existem regras dizendo em que arquivos as definições e as declarações devem ser feitas. O ponto aqui é que DEPENDENDO da maneira como a `struct` foi definida e declarada o efeito pode variar, alterando a visibilidade da `struct` e/ou de seus membros para o cliente da interface. O exemplo que vc apontou se trata de uma "estrutura opaca" que tem sua declaração no `.h` e sua definição no `.c`, porém, isso não é regra.